# Convert a sequence of dictionary keys to a set

Tags: f#, dictionary, set, sequence, key

The following code lists the  set of keys found in a dictionary sequence (each dict is basically a row from a database). (I want to convert the keys to a set so I can compare 2 db tables)

```
for seqitem in tblseq do
    let keyset = seqitem.Keys |> Set.ofSeq    // works correctly
    printfn ">>> List: %A; Item Type: %A" keyset
```

Rather than print the keyset however I want to return it from a function but am having a problem with type inference. Tried the following but it does not work;

What I want to do is return these values as either an array of list (rather than print them)

```
let get_keyset tblseq = 
                tblseq |> Seq.iter (fun x ->  
                       x.Keys |> Set.ofSeq                   
                     )
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Seq.map` as ildjarn suggests is one option (you may want to add `Array.ofSeq` to the end to get array of sets as you say in your qurestion).

An alternative approach is to use array comprehension:

```
let get_keyset (tblseq:seq<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>>) = 
    [| for x in tblseq -> x.Keys |> Set.ofSeq |]
```

The notation `[| .. |]` says that you want to create an array of elements and the expression following `->` specifies what should be produced as an element. The syntax is essentially just a nicer way for writing `Seq.map` (although it supports more features).

You can also use this syntax for creating sets (instead of calling `Set.ofSeq`). In this case, it doesn't make much sense, because `Set.ofSeq` is faster and sorhter, but sometimes it is quite neat option. It allows you to avoid type annotations, because you can get key of a dictionary using `KeyValue` pattern:

```
let get_keyset tblseq = 
    [| for x in tblseq ->
         set [ for (KeyValue(k, v)) in x -> k ] |]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Seq.map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370346.aspx) rather than `Seq.iter`:

```
let get_keyset tblseq =
    tblseq
    |> Seq.map (fun (x:Dictionary<_,_>) -> x.Keys |> set)
    |> Array.ofSeq
```